Multiple Linear Regression/ANOVA Help in Excel
I am working on a linear regression model and keep getting zero as my coefficients and the NUM! error as my p-value. I was told to organize the data this way but was then told by someone else that I cannot run a multiple linear regression if my independent variables are constant.
My dataset consists of 6 months of data for sales transactions. I am trying to see how demographic information (median income, median age, and number of competitors in the area) affect sales of the product. Since it is only a dataset with 6 months, I do not have any variance with my demographics in that time. My sales data is also an average for each month, which only gives me 6 total rows of data.
This is my averaged dataset for the 6 months.
Month   Transactions    Median Income   Median Age  Competitors
January 3414    126436.50   38.2    220
February    3174    126436.50   38.2    220
March   4117    126436.50   38.2    220
April   5022    126436.50   38.2    220
May 6574    126436.50   38.2    220
June    7074    126436.50   38.2    220
I've looked it up and ChatGPT has suggested maybe doing ANOVA testing instead because of my constant demographics variables. I tried to run a two-way ANOVA test with the income and age but still am not getting p-values. Tried to also run a one-way ANOVA and my p-values are large. Not even sure if ANOVA is a good test.
I'm still learning all of the tests and how to work them.
Any suggestions on what test would actually work best for this?

If you have explanatory variables which are constant (i.e., the same everywhere), why do you expect a non-zero coefficient?

I agree with you, I have come to learn this rather quickly. In your opinion, is any test of any sort going to give me an explanation or is this not a good dataset to be testing?

Your data is too limited to answer your questions above.  You have a single point of data for your demographics, the only independent variable remaining is time (only 6 months) so maybe the trend there but unlikely conclusive.


told by someone else that I cannot run a multiple linear regression if my independent variables are constant.

Indeed, there is not much you can do with this dataset (unless there is more too it than it appears so far). If you run a regression with a constant pedictor, there can be no sensible estimate (or p-value). Some software will likely throw an error, and others might simply show "NA" or something similar for the estimate, standard error, t-value and p-value.

Thank you, I assumed as much. Appreciate your explanation!
